# How to right code in Django and AngularJS?

Tags: python, angularjs, django

Now I am working with Django on server side and jQuery on client. Django views functions return templates with js code.

How it should look using AngularJS. Should I return JSON from Django and render response using JS ?

Many thanks!

Comment: What I do for my django+angular apps, I use django views to render my template but I load all my data by using ajax ($http) in angularjs

Comment: So you use django REST API and angularjs to retrieve data from server side ?

Comment: yes, you can say that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do, there are many ways, but yeah, ideally your routes and templates are handled in AngularJS, Angular requests information from Django or POSTs information, and they communicate using JSON.

You need to put your Angular templates and files in the static folder, you can use grunt or django-pipeline to better manage all the files you have.